# How to test latency of Flex messages

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds, amf

I have a system where clients connect via http streaming channels and use Producer and Consumer classes to dispatch and receive messages. I need to test the latency of messages in a way that adequately simulates real-world usage when the server is under load. I have 3 ideas for how this may be accomplished. Has anyone tried and succeeded or failed with these methods?

1. Use an out-of-the box test system like JMeter. Haven't found any that support streaming yet.
2. Use Selenium and FlexMonkey on BrowserMob to simulate actual users.
3. Use a client api (possibly from BlazeDS) that supports streaming and Flex messaging to write a custom testing framework. Haven't found a client api that supports streaming yet, any language would be OK.

Comment: I personally just use integration tests (unit tests that communicate with server) and call all functions asynchronously and saving start time, waiting for response, and log results.  That's an easy way of doing it.  If you want more of a load on the system, you'll need to use a server side library to simulate that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool for testing the performance of BlazeDS/LCDS, created by Adobe. Take a look [here](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/pdfs/data_services_portfolio.pdf) (there is a PDF file called Adobe LiveCycle Data Services 3 ES2 Performance Brief in the PDF portofolio, having a couple of attachments) .

Comment: I skimmed through that document and I didn't see anything about performance testing. Can you point me to the the section where it is discussed?

Comment: Oh I get it now, the pdf has some fancy Adobe magic built-in, and I have to read it with Adobe Reader, but it doesn't seem to work correctly with my version. Before I go any farther into getting this file to open, what kind of price range are the mentioned tools: open source, < $500, < $1k, < $5k, < $10k?

Comment: Open source. If you cannot make it run/configure let me know.

Comment: I can't get that pdf to open correctly. Can you just point me to the URL of the testing tool? Thanks

Comment: No, I'm not aware about a direct URL. Have you tried with Adobe X?